# Is there any way to number rows and columns on MineSweeper game in java console?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, numbers, minesweeper

I'm doing a minesweeper game in java console in which the user has to enter the x and y coordinates to pick the place he/she wants to open or flag. As you can see in the first picture, the grid consists in a 10x10 board of dots. As it is right now, the user has to count the row and column and only then he/she can write in the console the place he/she wants to sinalize. This is not really a good experience for the user, so I was wondering if there was any way to number the rows and columns from 1 to 10 so that it's easier for the user to pick the coordinate that he/she wants to pick. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84utF.png)

The code for the grid is the following

```js
public String appearanceAt(Pos p) {
        if (statuses[p.y][p.x] == StatusOfArea.CLOSED) {
            return ". ";
        }
        if (statuses[p.y][p.x] == StatusOfArea.flagEDASBOMB) {
            return "* ";
        }
        int count = countMineNeighbors(p);
        if (count == 0) {
            return "0 ";
        }
        return + count + " ";
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you can use -1 offset in 2d array access to use 1-10 values. (last if is useless)

Comment: You could print 0123456789 as a header before you print the board. And likewise on the left side of the board. I'd use 0-9 because it gives you ten numbers without having to worry about more than one digit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can do the top part, but I'm not so sure on how do it on the left side... I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I see you have encapsulated the Position detail in an object.

You could similarly encapsulate the 2 dimensional array in a Board class.

Board's print method could:

- print all columns in the first row
- print the row number at the beginning of each row

This method could also make a call to a getStatus function to determine what you need to show on user input

It would look like this

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
A . . . . . . . . . .
B . . . . . . . . . .
C . . . . . . . . . .
D . . . . . . . . . .
E . . . . . . . . . .
F . . . . . . . . . .
G . . . . . . . . . .
H . . . . . . . . . .
I . . . . . . . . . .
J . . . . . . . . . .
```

The user would enter input as "D 5". It would be up to the InputHandler to translate it and set Position object accordingly.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I will try that out. Thank you very much!